# Doob's submartingale stopping theorem in the context of the submartingale problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, proof-writing

Let

$$X^\omega_f (t, w) = f(w(t)) - f(w(t \wedge \tau)) - \frac{1}{2} \int_{t \wedge \tau}^t \Delta f(w(s))\, ds$$

be a $P^\tau_\omega$-submartingale.

1) Why Doob's submartingale stopping theorem implies that for each $n$ $\{X^\omega_f (t + \tau \wedge n), \mathcal{F}_{t + \tau \wedge n}, t \geq 0\}$ is a $P^\tau_\omega$- submartingale

2) Why letting $n \to \infty$ continuity and bounded convergence imply that  $\{1_{\{\tau < \infty \}}X^\omega_f (\cdot + \tau ), \mathcal{F}_{\cdot + \tau }, \}$ is a $P^\tau_\omega$- submartingale

**remark (2):** I would understand 2) if instead of $t + \tau \wedge n$ we had $t \wedge \tau \wedge n$ note the missing parenthesis. Is it $(t + \tau) \wedge n$ or $t + (\tau \wedge n)$ I guess it is $t + (\tau \wedge n)$ since this gives us a bounded stopping time, wich is well suited for the optional stopping theorem.

**remark (3):** in case $\tau < \infty$ continuity implies $X^\omega_f (t + \tau ) = \lim_n X^\omega_f (t + \tau \wedge n) $ point wise and

$$\Bbb{E} [X^\omega_f ( t + \tau \wedge n) \vert \mathcal{F}_{s+ \tau \wedge n}] \geq X^\omega_f (s + \tau \wedge n)$$

How to use bounded convergence theorem  ($f \in C^\infty_c$) to justify
$$\Bbb{E} [X^\omega_f ( t + \tau ) \vert \mathcal {F}_{s+ \tau} ] = \lim_{n} \Bbb{E} [ X^\omega_f ( t + \tau \wedge n) \vert \mathcal{F}_{s+ \tau \wedge n}] \geq X^\omega_f (s + \tau \wedge n)$$

How do we show that

$$\Bbb{E} [1_{\tau<\infty}X^\omega_f ( t + \tau) \vert \mathcal{F}_{s+ \tau \wedge n}] \geq 1_{\tau<\infty}X^\omega_f (s + \tau \wedge n)$$

**references and comments:** This question comes from Ruth Williams thesis. -Brownian motion with oblique reflection at the boundary - 1983

Here $P^\tau_\omega$ is a regular conditional probability distribution of $P$ given $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ and we use $w$ to represent a generic element of $C[0\infty)$ to avoid confusion with the $\omega$ used to fix the conditional probability.